# Marginal effect of squared variable in Probit Model

Tags: interaction, stata, nonlinear-regression, probit

I want to estimate the following probit model

$employed_t=\beta_1 age + \beta_2 age^2$

and I use the Stata code

```
probit employed c.age##c.age
```

Using the command `margins` I obtain the marginal effect of $age$ including the effect through the quadratic terms if included in the model (see: [How do I interpret a probit model in Stata?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/42956/how-do-i-interpret-a-probit-model-in-stata)).

How do I obtain the marginal effect for the quadratic terms $age^2$?

Is this procedure correct?

`probit employed c.age##c.age`

`sum age`

`local m=r(mean)`

`local x1 _b[c.age]*'m'+_b[c.age#c.age]*'m'+_b[_cons]`

`nlcom 2*normd('x1')*_b[c.age#c.age]-('x1')*normd('x1')*(_b[c.age]+2*_b[c.age#c.age]*'r')`

Comment: I don't think this is a sensible question. Stata's `margins` deal with everything you need. There's no effect of `age^2` that would be separate from the effect of `age`; there is simply a non-linear effect of `age` that `margins` treats perfectly fine for you.

Comment: Ok, but I am interested in the size/sign of the marginal effect of $age^2$.

Comment: The size and sign are not very meaningful.

Comment: It depends. But the point is: in a table I need to report both the margins.

Comment: The marginal effect (on the linear predictor scale) for the quadratic term is just the coefficient.  Maybe you're confused because it is sort of weird to only ask for a marginal effect when two variables will be so obviously correlated as a polynomial epansion inevitably will be.

Comment: Using a linear probability model I can directly interpret the $\beta$ of $age^2$. This is not true using a logit/probit.

Comment: "On the linear predictor scale".  Which is to say on the scale of the normal cdf.

Answer (score 2):

I am inclined to agree with @StasK's comment. However, something like what you want is feasible, though a little tricky to interpret. What I propose below tells you how the marginal effect of $x$ varies with $x$.

You know that the conditional mean of the dependent variable in a probit model is
$$\mathbb{Pr}[y=1 \vert x,z]=\Phi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi).$$
The variable $x$ is what we care about. The vector $z$ contains some other covariates. $\Phi(.)$ is the standard normal cdf, and $\varphi(.)$ is is the standard normal pdf, which will be used below.

The marginal effect of $x$ is
$$\frac{\partial \mathbb{Pr}[y=1 \vert x,z]}{\partial x}=\varphi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi)\cdot(\beta + 2\cdot\gamma \cdot x).$$
The change in the marginal effect is the second derivative
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \mathbb{Pr}[y=1 \vert x,z]}{\partial x^2} =
\varphi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi)\cdot(2\cdot\gamma) +(\beta + 2\cdot\gamma \cdot x)\cdot\varphi'(\alpha + \beta  \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi).
$$

Since [$\varphi′(x)=−x \cdot \varphi(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Symmetries_and_derivatives), this "simplifies" to

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \mathbb{Pr}[y=1 \vert x,z]}{\partial x^2} =
\varphi(\alpha + \beta \cdot  x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi)\cdot \left[ 2\cdot\gamma -(\beta + 2\cdot\gamma \cdot x)^2\cdot(\alpha + \beta  \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2+z'\pi)\right].
$$

Note that this is a function of $x$ and $z$s, so we can evaluate this quantity at various possible values. Also note that while the first term is surely positive since it is a normal density, it's hard to sign the second term even if you know the sign and magnitude of the coefficients.

Assuming that I didn't screw up the derivative, here's how I might actually do this in Stata:

```
#delimit;
sysuse auto, clear;
probit foreign c.mpg##c.mpg c.weight, coefl;
/* At own values of covarites */
margins, expression(normalden(predict(xb))*(2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg] - predict(xb)*(_b[c.mpg]+2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg]*mpg)^2));
/* At chosen values of covarites */
margins, expression(normalden(predict(xb))*(2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg] - predict(xb)*(_b[c.mpg]+2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg]*mpg)^2)) at(mpg=20 weight=3000);
/* At avermpg value of covariates */
margins, expression(normalden(predict(xb))*(2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg] - predict(xb)*(_b[c.mpg]+2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg]*mpg)^2)) atmeans;
```

If I was doing this myself and feeling lazy, I might use adjacent reverse contrasts. For instance, here's the second derivative evaluated at 4 values of $x$:

```
margins, expression(normalden(predict(xb))*(2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg] - predict(xb)*(_b[c.mpg]+2*_b[c.mpg#c.mpg]*mpg)^2)) at(mpg = (10 20 30 40));
```

Here's a comparison of the derivatives. This compares the marginal effects of mpg at mpg of x+1 to the marginal effect at mpg of x:

```
margins, dydx(mpg) at(mpg = (10 11 20 21 30 31 40 41)) contrast(atcontrast(ar(2(2)8)._at) wald);
```

Note how close the two commands' outputs are, but the second is so much easier.

I don't know what r is your code, so I can't verify if what you have is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a large number of observations (>1mln) then "inteff" is not working. I am able to compute the marginal effect manually when the interaction is between two dummies but I am not sure how to do it with a continuous variable (i.e. the squared term).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use stata for GLMs (like probit), so maybe I'm missing something specific to the context, but anyway:

What you're doing is modeling
$$
g(E[employed]) = \beta_0 + \beta_1age + \beta_2age^2
$$
where $g(.)$ is the normal cdf.  You can follow the following procedure to interpret your coeffcients (which is almost exactly the same for logit):

1. Draw or graph for yourself the normal cdf.  It is sigmoidal.
2. Note the intercept ($\beta_0$) on your x-axis, and draw a line up to where it intersects the normal cdf.
3. For a given age $A$, move $\beta_1 A + \beta_2 A^2$ from your intercept.  Note the point on the x-axis, and draw a line up to where it intersects the function.
4. Draw a line to the left, to see where it intersects the y-axis.  This is a probability.
5. Voila:  you've got the fitted value of $\widehat{employed}$ for a given level of age.  Over a gradient of values of $A$, you get a quadratic marginal effect curve.

Comment: I really like this!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't adjust for $\mbox{age}$ in this model when including $\mbox{age}^2$ as a regressor, you are forcing the instantaneous rate of employment decrease to be zero at $\mbox{age}=0$. That might seem contrived, but if you take a change of variable:

$$\mbox{age}^* = \frac{\mbox{age} - 50}{5}$$

You might see why that would be a stupid idea. You can prove that any data with a strong non-zero linear term in a quadratic mean model will look locally consistent with a reduced model dropping the linear term. So don't let the data decide which terms to use. Use them both as a form of "added assurance" or "added insurance".

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. The question was about computing the ME.