# How to interpret log-transformed predictors in probit regression?

Tags: regression, probit, binary-data, logarithm

I am running a probit model with several continous and one log-transformed predictor (firm size as total assets). I am unsure how to interpret the coefficient of -0.341 on that variable. I used the natural logarithm to transform the data. Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Probit coefficients don't have a straightforward interpretation like the ones in logit (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/42956/how-do-i-interpret-a-probit-model-in-stata)). Use marginal effects (if in Stata, the margins command) to obtain the change in $Pr(y)$ for a one-unit increase in $x$ for interpreting the coefficients of a probit.

If your predictor would not be log transformed, you could stop by here, as you would have the change in $Pr(y)$ by a one-unit increase in $x$. Log transformed variables require one more step, because for them a one-unit increase in $x$ means multiplying $x$ by the base (in this case $e$).

In this case, the marginal effects that you would obtain for your log transformed predictor would show the change in $Pr(y)$ for a 2.7182818285-fold change in $x$. Not very pretty. Your best bet is to use a logarithm with base 2 or base 10, so that you can interpret this as the marginal effects as the change in $Pr(y)$ for a two-fold or a ten-fold change in $x$. See [this discussion](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/950118-marginal-effects-in-probit-model-for-a-log-transformed-variable) on Statalist for another example.